# Most basic equation: Heart rate is in units of bpm. What are the units of "b"?

Tags: dimensional-analysis

This is the most simple question in the world, but it is surprisingly difficult to explain to a student.  The heart rate is measured in bpm, beats per minute.  Minutes are a true unit. Beats are not a true unit. However, we are using beats as if it where a unit.  I'm not sure how to explain this to a student, and I'm confusing myself.   Please help.

Comment: It's a [dimensionless quantity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_quantity#:~:text=All%20pure%20numbers%20are%20dimensionless,may%20also%20be%20considered%20dimensionless.).  Thus the dimension of "beats per minute" is $\frac 1{\text{time}}$.

Comment: How do you reckon a beat is not a unit? Sure, it is not one of the standard SI/imperial units, but it is clear enough what it refers to and is measuring/describing, surely?

Comment: @lulu  But in the medical world, it is allways written as bpm.  If you write it as 1/time, no one will understand.

Comment: Are you familiar with [hertz (Hz)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hertz)?  A unit is $s^{-1}$, or in plain English, _per second_.

Comment: @Eevee I agree that we all clearly understand the concept.  However, if a beat is not one of the standard SI/imperial units, then it is not a unit.  There are no other units.   I applogize if we are going in circles.

Comment: @Chris  I was speaking of dimension (you tagged "dimensional analysis").  If all time measurements scaled up by $2$, your bpm would decline by a factor of $\frac 12$.

Answer (score 2):

BPM means "beats per minute" but that doesn't mean that "beats" is a "unit."  Otherwise we could have an infinite number of "units" based on counting other things.

For instance:  How many red two-door cars with sagging taillights and broken headlights with expired license plates pass by a point on this road in a minute?  Oh, $7$, you say?  Well I suppose the rate is 7 RTDCSTBHELPPM."

So now "RTDCSTBHELP" is a "unit"?!?!

Insane.

Comment: Thanks for the laugh!  Let me please pretend I'm the student.  I would say to you that you can treat "beats" mathematically as if they were a unit.  All the same operations apply.   So, isn't it some kind of effective unit?

Answer (score 1):

@Stork led me to the answer, but he didn't quite get there.  A "beat" is a "counting unit". This is the term I've been looking for!   A "dozen" is also a counting unit.  If you google "counting unit", you will find it is a fairly common term.   So, if a "beat" is a counting unit, then what kind of unit is a "second". A "second" is  a "measuring unit".   This implies that counting and measuring should be treated as distinct activities, which makes sense.  I had never really stopped to realize that counting and measuring are distinct.

I do apologize for dwelling on this, but I think this terminology will clarify matters for students.

ps.  This ancient [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2970971?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) appears to discuss the distinctions.